# JavaScript recursion variable value undefined

Tags: javascript

When I run the below `JS`, the console correctly logs `a` as string: "foo", but then the return value is undefined. `typeof()` also says it's a string. There is no change from line 5 to 6 (the `console.log` and the `return`), so how can this spontaneously become undefined?

```
let a = "foo";
let c = 0;
function test() {
  if (c === 5) {
    console.log(a);
    return a;
  } else {
    c++;
    test();
  }
}
```

Comment: Or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508709/javascript-recursion-function-returning-undefined) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762312/javascript-recursive-function-returning-undefined) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36069423/javascript-recursive-function-returns-undefined-for-existing-value). Please do some [basic research](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+recursive+function+returns+undefined+site:stackoverflow.com) before asking.

Answer (score 2):

In your recursive call, use `return test()`:

```
let a = "foo";
let c = 0;
function test() {
  if (c === 5) {
    console.log(a);
    return a;
  } else {
    c++;
    return test();
  }
}
```

**Explanation:** Consider the first call of `test()` in your original code. If `c` is 5, it will return a value, but otherwise, it won't return anything. Sure it will execute a second call of `test()`, but it will not return the value of that call to your main program. This is why the `return` statement is needed. And the same logic applies to all calls of `test()` where `c` is not equal to `5`.